# Alternate formulation of conditional independence.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, definition

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables valued in $A$ and $B$ respectively, both supported on a probability space $\Omega$.
Saying that $X$ and $Y$ are independent is equivalent to saying that the push forward measure of the map $(X, Y):\Omega\to A\times B$ is the product of the push foraward of $X$ and the push forward of $Y$.

I am wondering if there is a similar way to state the notion of conditional independence.
That is, suppose $X_1, X_2, Y$ are random variables such $X_1$ and $X_2$ are indepdent conditioned on $Y$. Is there a way to say this in terms of push forwards (or in a more measure theoretic spirit).

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathsf{P})$ be a probability space. The image measure of $(X_1,X_2,Y)$ can be represented as follows. For Borel sets $A_1$, $A_2$, and $B$,
$$
(\mathsf{P}\circ (X_1,X_2,Y)^{-1})(A_1\times A_2\times B)=\int_B\mu_1(A_1,y)\mu_2(A_2,y)(\mathsf{P}\circ Y^{-1})(dy),
$$
where $\mu_j$ is a Markov kernel satisfying
$$
(\mathsf{P}\circ (X_j,Y)^{-1})(A_j\times B)=\int_B\mu_j(A_j,y)(\mathsf{P}\circ Y^{-1})(dy).
$$